# How to I functionally access an SQL table's table name?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a set of tables that I am conflating together. I want to be able to go back and access the 'raw' data later if  I need to add more. The way I'm doing this by adding a reference column to the conflation table that will contain the table name of the table from which the data came from.

How can I access the names of my tables as I query from them?

EDIT: Details:

The table I'm creating looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE combined_things WITH OIDS AS
(SELECT
thing1.name
thing1.shape
FROM
public.thing1_source_table

UNION

SELECT
thing2.name
thing2.shape
FROM
public.thing2_source_table);
```

And I want to add the "source" field:

```
ALTER TABLE combined_things ADD COLUMN source_id character varying(100);
ALTER TABLE comnined_things SET COLUMN source_id = {table_name}
```

And I don't know how to pull the {table_name}

Comment: Maybe if you included some examples, it would be easier to help you. I can kind of visualise it, but more detail would really help.

Comment: From _where_? In a stored procedure? Simply build a statement. From elsewhere? Well - more (at least some!) details would probably be most helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add them as a string constant when you create the table

```
CREATE TABLE combined_things WITH OIDS AS
(SELECT
thing1.name,
thing1.shape,
CAST('public.thing1_source_table' AS CHAR(100)) source_id
FROM
public.thing1_source_table

UNION

SELECT
thing2.name,
thing2.shape,
'public.thing2_source_table'
FROM
public.thing2_source_table);
```

Note that there is no way of casting the column to varchar

Comment: AFAIK, this is the most common way of doing it... Mainly because you've got to write the SQL to get the data from the table anyway, so you know which tables you've accessed.